# Можно ли разово присвоить символы к char

Tags: c++

Например у меня есть код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

bool GetPath(char* folder)
{
    if (SHGetFolderPathA(0, CSIDL_PROFILE, 0, 0, folder) == S_OK)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool fileExist(const char* path)
{
    if (GetFileAttributesA(path) != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char* path;
    path = (char*)malloc(MAX_PATH);
    GetPath(path);
    if (fileExist(lstrcatA(path, "\\AppData")))
    {
        std::cout << path << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    free(path);
    return 1;
}
```

Могу ли я как то разово в условии в main присвоить переменной path определенную строку?
Или для этого мне нужно обьявлять новую переменную?
Если я использую lstrcatA то переменная меняется на всю программу, а мне нужно лишь присвоить в рамках условия

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? Что такое переменные и как они работают или что такое указатели и как они работают?

Comment: не стоит использовать функции с суффиксом `A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот это выражение

```
lstrcatA(path, "\\AppData")
```

модифицирует переменную path и возвращает указатель на нее. И я так понимаю, это и есть проблемой.

Оставим за кадром то, что Вы ставите метку с++, используете cout, но при этом не используете std::string.

```
char path[MAX_PATH+1];
char apppath[MAX_PATH+1];
GetPath(path);
lstrcatA(apppath, path);
lstrcatA(apppath, "\\AppData")
if (fileExist(apppath))
{
    // будем последовательны
    puts(apppath);
}
puts(path);
```

Comment: Вы меня не совсем так поняли, мне нужно будет переменную path использовать многократно и проверять существуют ли папки/файлы, например проверить существует ли в папке сначало 1-й файл потом 2-й потом 3-й и для такой проверки мне придётся, либо заполнять нулями path при след. файле либо обьявлять дополнительные переменные. std я использовал исключительно для вывода(привык уже) но меня интересует не string а именно char

Comment: я Вас понял правильно:) в char Вы не сможете сохранить путь. ну никак. Но никто не мешает переиспользовать вторую переменную сколько раз, сколько нужно. Даже в плюсах, когда Вы пишете s + "test",Вы создаете новый временный объект

Comment: Да всё вы были правы всё таки я пришел к выводу что стоит использовать 2-ю переменную

Comment: в любом случае, я бы создал функцию "isDirExist(const char* head, const char* tail) {}`, и Ваш код может сильно упроститься. Может.